# Vectorize computation on mesh in Python

Tags: python, vectorization

I have matrix:
`f = np.zeros((M, N))`
filled with some float numbers. I want to replace each internal point `f[i, j]` with average of its neighbors:
`f_new[i,j] = (f[i-1, j] + f[i+1, j] + f[i, j+1] + f[i, j-1])/4`. There is an obvious way to do it:

```
f_new = f.copy()
for i in range(1, M-1):
    for j in range(1, N-1):
       f_new[i,j] = (f[i-1, j] + f[i+1, j] + f[i, j+1] + f[i, j-1])/4
f = f_new
```

Is there a more elegant (vectorized) way of doing this in Python? Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you to work out a more complete example (including some input and expected output). I would also make sure that the code works (right now it gives me a number of errors), before investigating how to improve it... Anyway, probably the operation you are looking for is likely a uniform filter (which you can find in `scipy` for example).

Comment: norok2, thank you for your reply. I should have tested my example before posting it. I've updated the code. I'll take a look at uniform filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). There are multiple open-source implementations, but [scipy's](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) works:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal
import time

f = np.random.random((1000, 1000))

# -------- For loop
start = time.perf_counter()
f_pad = np.pad(f, ((1, 1), (1, 1)), 'constant', constant_values=0) # pad the array

f_new = f_pad.copy()
for i in range(1, f.shape[0]+1):
    for j in range(1, f.shape[1]+1):
        f_new[i,j] = (f_pad[i-1, j] + f_pad[i+1, j] + f_pad[i, j+1] + f_pad[i, j-1])/4.
f_new = f_new[1:-1, 1:-1]
print("For loop time:", str(time.perf_counter() - start))

# -------- Convolution
start = time.perf_counter()
f_newer = signal.convolve2d(f, 
                            np.array([[0, 0.25, 0],
                                      [0.25, 0, 0.25],
                                      [0, 0.25, 0]]),
                            mode='same',
                            boundary='fill',
                            fillvalue=0)
print("Convolution time:", str(time.perf_counter() - start))

# >> For loop time: 1.4474979060469195
# >> Convolution time: 0.0972418460296467
```